# How do I fill the gap between paneling and coving?

Tags: ceiling, plaster, paneling

I've put up some coving before I did some paneling on one wall.

The paneling is level as I used a laser level however the coving was stuck to the wall & ceiling without a level.

The gap between the coving and horizontal panel increases and decreases throughout the length **and** goes in and out.

My question is what do I do with it - do I fill it and how?

If I fill it what do I do when the coving that dips in? I'd have to fill it in closer the the curve to maintain/blend that curve right.

[image]
<sup>Click to embiggen</sup>

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Most likely you'll be the only person to ever notice it - hardly anybody goes around looking at the joints at the top of the wall. Still, you either put the two things in level (rarely works with the average not level house) or you put the two things in so they fit each other, not one this way, one that way, and be amazed at your house not being level. **Next** time. My "not secret" for coving that fits wall and ceiling as perfectly as I want to bother is to build it by shaping plaster or drywall compound, not applying trim.

Answer (score 6):

Carpentry lesson in hindsight: *Level* isn't always the right move, and flush (or *nearly* flush) joints are problematic. Ideally the cove would've been brought out a bit for a more consistent bottom reveal (or installed *over* the paneling), and the paneling should've been set tight (as was possible).

FreeMan is probably right given the state of progress. However, I'd seriously consider removing the coving, placing spacers the thickness of the paneling frames behind it, and reinstalling. A heavier bottom reveal would really be classier. You could then easily caulk the bottom joint just to fill any slight gaps, tooling off any excess.

Comment: What would a heavier bottom reveal look like?

Comment: Just like if there wasn't panel molding below it.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to fill the gaps with wood filler, drywall mud, plaster, or other filler material that's compatible with the materials you've already used. Carefully apply the material to make it as smooth as possible on application, then sand gently to get it to the final shape.

You're at the "trim carpentry" stage, so this is the part that's visible under the paint (assuming this will be painted), so any and everything you do here will telegraph through the paint and *probably* be amplified by the paint, as well. Make sure you take your time, be patient, and get it right so you're happy with the paint job later.

Comment: If I'd fill the gap what would I do where there's a gap and  the coving is 'sunken in' (in relation to the panel)?

Comment: Fill the gaps with your filler material and put some of your filler material on the low side and trowel it smooth with the high side. Once troweled as smooth as you can get it (don't over work mud, plaster, etc - it'll dry out and crumble off), let it set, then gently sand smooth to _your_ desired level of perfection.

Comment: Okay, I'll do this, I'll let you know how I fair. I'll probably get around to it in about 2-3 weeks time.